# Why does the Doctor confess at the end of Heaven Sent?

Tags: doctor-who

In Heaven Sent the Doctor endures an almost unbearable torment (as suggested by his monologue) to keep the secret of the Hybrid secret, as it's "very very dangerous", and yet when he finally escapes the first thing he does is confess the secret:

> You can probably still hear me... so just between ourselves... you've got the prophecy wrong. The Hybrid is not half Dalek. Nothing is half Dalek. The Daleks would never allow that. The Hybrid destined to conquer Gallifrey and stand in its ruins... is me.

Why does he do this? It seems to completely undermine the very thing that drove him to not give up and confess at the start.

Comment: Well, given that he just spent billions of years punching through superdiamond to get out, now that he *is* out, it doesn’t really matter whether they know or not — they’re going *down*, bro. Whereas if he confessed while still trapped in the confession disc, then they can make sure to keep him in there.

Comment: @Paul No. After the last confession, he was going to be freed. That was the whole point of the last room.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. The promise of freedom could have been deceptive or an outright lie. Given what he confessed, had he confessed it under (presumably) The Time Lords' control, it seems unlikely that they would have sent him on to Gallifrey.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: and your source for that is...?

Comment: @Paul The Doctor himself said that. TARDIS is one confession away. Something like that...

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: oh, yeah that’s true. Still, he can’t exactly know for sure. And he might be saying that that’s the implication that his captors want him to believe. Letting the Doctor go after doing something like this to him doesn’t seem like a great idea.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 though that also reveals further deception from his captors: they showed him the TARDIS through the diamond wall...but it wasn't actually there.  They could just've easily planned to kill him after his final confession.

Comment: @Paul The question is from Doctor's perspective. So, what Doctor believed is what matters.

Comment: Did they show him the TARDIS? Or did he just assume that "Home" meant the TARDIS?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: sure, I agree.

Comment: He assumed "Home" meant the TARDIS. The series has long since established that the TARDIS is the only home The Doctor really admits to most of the time. Only when he's feeling sentimental about Gallifrey--like right after he succeeded in saving it rather than destroying it--does he think of it as home, and something usually happens to disabuse him of the idea...

Comment: @MichaelRushton In your quote, does he really say *me*, or does he in fact say *Me* ??? ;)

Answer (score 9):

Through most of the story, the Doctor assumes he's in a trap set by someone else, to whom he doesn't want to tell his deepest secrets.

Once he escapes, he realizes that he was inside his own Confession Dial the entire time. As long as he retains possession of the Confession Dial, his secrets are nominally safe, or so he believes.

> In addition, the entire time the Doctor was hammering away at the wall of azbantium, he believed the TARDIS, and safety, lay on the other side, giving him a reason to resist--he believes he can escape the entire situation. Instead, he wound up on Gallifrey, which probably completely changes his internal calculus. If we assume that the Doctor is always trying to answer the question, "How am I going to win?", then the Doctor has clearly decided that embracing, rather than escaping, the Prophecy of the Hybrid is the way to win in the situation he finally found himself.

Comment: Wait a sec ... the dial was his??  Who put him in there then? Why?

Comment: @JK. Wasn't Missey very interested in his confession dial at the start of the season? It would be unlike Moffat to *not* tie these sort of events together.

Comment: watch the previous episode.

Comment: @JK the time lords put him in there, Ashilda made a deal with the time lords like she says "I made a deal to protect the street. they take you and the key so you cant be traced, I do as they tell me and the street is safe". The doctor then hands over the confession dial. The Teleport sends him inside the dial and ashilda hands over the dial to the time lords with him in it. as for why  it will be made clear in the finale, bit of a cheat they had to send a message through the crack in the universe last time but now they are in constant contact with a human on earth how did that one happen?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, **he lied** (now that's something new... but at that moment he probably decided to *become* the Hybrid, see below) as the [transcript of "Hell Bent" shows](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/35-12.html) (emphasis mine):

> [Cloisters]
>
>  ASHILDR: Sometimes you do. It's always the way with things we'd rather
>  forget. You remember now, though, don't you? Tell me, Doctor, **who is
>  the Hybrid? Who threatens all of Time and Space?**
>  DOCTOR: Oh, but that's easy. That's very, very easy. **The Hybrid is you.**
>
>  [Tardis]
>
>  ASHILDR [on scanner]: I'm human, with a little bit of Mire inside me.
>  **The Hybrid is supposed to be half Time Lord, half Dalek.**
>  DOCTOR [on scanner]: **No, it isn't.**
>
>  [Cloisters]
>
>  DOCTOR: **The actual prophecy specifies only two warrior races.** The
>  Daleks and the Time Lords have made assumptions, of course. And they
>  would. Humans and the Mire, both warrior races. It fits perfectly.
>  ASHILDR: It's an interesting theory.
>  DOCTOR: Do you have a better one?
>  ASHILDR: By your own reasoning, **why couldn't the Hybrid be half Time
>  Lord, half human?** Tell me, Doctor, I've always wondered. You're a Time
>  Lord, you're a high-born Gallifreyan. **Why is it you spend so much time
>  on Earth?** (Because in the Movie, the Master worked out that the
>  Doctor's really half-human - on his mother's side.)
>  DOCTOR: **That's
>  your best theory? I'm the Hybrid?** I ran away from Gallifrey because I
>  was afraid of myself? **That doesn't make any sense.**
>  ASHILDR: It makes
>  perfect sense, and you know it. Am I right? Is it true?
>  DOCTOR: Does it matter?
>  ASHILDR: No. Because **I have a better theory.**
>  DOCTOR: Really?
>  ASHILDR: **What if the Hybrid wasn't one person, but two?**
>  DOCTOR: Two?
>  ASHILDR: A dangerous combination of **a passionate and
>  powerful Time Lord and a young woman so very similar to him**.
>
>  [Tardis]
>
>  ASHILDR [on scanner]: **Companions who are willing to push each other to
>  extremes.**
>  DOCTOR [on scanner]: She's my friend. She's just my friend.
>  ASHILDR [on scanner]: How did you meet her?
>  CLARA: Missy!
>
>  [Cloisters]
>
>  DOCTOR: Missy.
>  ASHILDR: Missy. The Master. The lover of chaos, who
>  wants you to love it, too. She's quite the matchmaker.
>  DOCTOR: Clara's my friend.
>  ASHILDR: I know. **And you're willing to risk all of Time and
>  Space because you miss her. One wonders what the pair of you will get
>  up to next.**
>  DOCTOR: Nothing. Nothing at all. I know I went too far. I
>  get it. That's why I'm doing what I'm doing.
>  ASHILDR: And what would that be?
>  DOCTOR: I'm taking her back to Earth. Somewhere safe,
>  somewhere out of the way. I'm going to wipe her memory of every last
>  detail of me.

So the gist of it is, the Doctor didn't actually know until Ashildr rubbed his nose in the answer. And the Hybrid is not *him*

> alone, but him and Clara together.

His claim to be the Hybrid is rather based on the prophecy he quotes,

> The Hybrid destined to conquer Gallifrey and stand in its ruins...

Well, after what the Timelords did to him what they "just"<sup>1</sup> did he basically lets them (or at least the confession dial) know that now he has decided to *become* the Hybrid and tear Gallifrey down. Obviously, after having had some time to think about it, he didn't but rather set in motion the events of "Hell Bent" which in turn *did*

> threaten all of time and space because the Doctor wanted to save Clara and *thus* almost fulfilling the prophecy.

Comment: ¹) "just" doesn't seem to do justice to those billions of years...

Answer (score 1):

He was speaking metaphorically.

The Hybrid was said to be a being that would wreak havoc on Gallifrey.

By saying *he* was the Hybrid, he didn't actually mean he was the Hybrid that everyone was talking about, but that he was going to wreak havoc on Gallifrey. It was a statement of anger: he was coming to get them.

Like if I get really pissed off at you and I say, "y'know what? *I'm* the big bad wolf. You'd better watch your back" it's not an admission that I'm literally a wolf.

Comment: This is plain simple wrong. It was never a plan of The Doctor to wreak havoc on Gallifrey. He just wanted to kick the President out of Planet.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433: Considering his plan was to save Clara and thereby _"fracture time itself"_, thus ruining Gallifrey as well as pretty much everything else, you may want to reconsider your certainty. Indeed, the realisation that this was a really stupid plan that went _way_ too far was the whole point of the last quarter of the episode.

Comment: ss-3 i would dis agree planning a military coup on a planets president and high council then leaving the planet to fend for itself could e deemed havoc i agree when he said he was the hybrid it was for the audience to sit and think at the credits " OMG he is gonna tear s**t up!"

Comment: Sorry for overlooking your answer before I posted [mine](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/132783/769), I totally agree with you since that's what the following episode suggest. Except I don't think at this point he had _any_ plan except for tearing down Gallifreay. +1 anyways

Answer (score 0):

The Doctor was lying.

> "Nothing is half Dalek. The Daleks would never allow that."

Hardy har har.

[Daleks in Manhattan](https://doctoraday.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/screen-shot-2013-02-02-at-6-35-33-pm.png?w=551&h=309). 'Nuff said.

Comment: Well that was the [Cult of Skaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult_of_Skaro): “They are described as an elite organisation created by the Emperor of the Daleks to think as their enemies think and find new ways of surviving”. And as the Wikipedia article mentions, at the time of *Daleks in Manhattan*, they believe themselves to be the last of their race, so they’re kind of desperate.

Comment: There's also the Witch's Familiar when Davros uses the Doctor's regeneration energy to renew the Daleks, with Davros explicitly bringing up the half Dalek, half Time Lord prophesy as he does so.

Comment: The Ninth Doctor faced a whole army of half-human Daleks *created by the Emperor*, but the Doctor can be forgiven if he forgot events that, for him, occurred over a millennium ago. That's why he keeps diaries.

Comment: @JohnSensebe Those weren't half human Daleks, they were real Daleks, just made with human cells for the base material. Like Davros did later with his own cells in _Journey's End_. The Dalek/Human hybrid in _Daleks in Manhattan_ was something else entirely.

Comment: @MrLister - Rose explicitly calls them "half human" in "The Parting of the Ways".